# Subset based on first three numbers

Tags: r, subset

I have a very large data set of variables and I need to subset based on the first three numbers of the zip code.  I'm not sure how to do this and would appreciate any help you can provide.

How would I subset this example dput to remove all those zip codes that start with 721.  Note that I can't simple do a greater than (>) since there are zip codes large than 721 Thanks!

dput :

```
data <- structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AR", 
  "IL", "MO"), class = "factor"), zip = c(72003L, 72042L, 72073L, 
  72166L, 72038L, 72055L, 72160L, 72026L, 72048L, 72140L, 72003L, 
  72042L, 72073L, 72166L, 72038L, 72055L, 72160L, 72026L, 72048L, 
  72140L)), .Names = c("state", "zip"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data :

```
   state   zip
1     AR 72003
2     AR 72042
3     AR 72073
4     AR 72166
5     AR 72038
6     AR 72055
7     AR 72160
8     AR 72026
9     AR 72048
10    AR 72140
11    AR 72003
12    AR 72042
13    AR 72073
14    AR 72166
15    AR 72038
16    AR 72055
17    AR 72160
18    AR 72026
19    AR 72048
20    AR 72140
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `substr`

```
data[substr(data$zip, 1,3)!=721,]
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[substr(zip,1,3)!=721]
```

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
      filter(substr(zip, 1,3)!=721)
```

Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(data, zip, 'zip1', '(...).*', FALSE) %>% 
                              filter(zip1!=721) %>% 
                              select(-zip1)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun.  Is this possible to do with dplyr through `filter`?

Comment: @Amstell You can use the same command inside `filter` also. Please check the update

Comment: Is there a quick way to add multiple 3-digit codes without having to write out the entire line again, such as `c(720, 721)` ?  This doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Amstell You have use `%in%` instead of `==` for more than one elements. ie.  `data %>% filter(!substr(zip, 1,3) %in% c(720, 721))`  I didn't use `%in%` because it may be a little slower compared to `==`